# getting htaccess rewrite rules to rewrite only specific urls

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I only want to rewrite this specific url:

http://www.website.co.uk/php/project.php?project=anythingHere
to
http://www.website.co.uk/php/project/anythingHere

this works fine but when I go to http://www.website.co.uk/php/project/anythingHere
it has changed all the links as well (style sheets, javascript, hyperlinks... things I don't want to change). for example:

http://www.website.co.uk/php/index.php
to
http://www.website.co.uk/php/project/index.php

---

This is what I have already

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website.com\.co\.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.website.com\.co\.uk$
RewriteRule ^clients$ "http\:\/\/website.com\.co\.uk\/billing\/index\.php" [R=301]
RewriteRule ^project/([^/]*)$ /php/project.php?project=$1
```

Comment: I don't see a rule that would cause that. Did you test with `[R=301]` before? It could be that an old redirect is still cached. Use `[R]` instead and clear the cache of your browser and see if the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?website\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^clients/?$ http://website.co.uk/billing/index.php [NC,L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(php/project)\.php\?project=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(php/project)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1.php?project=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```